# Efficient way to compute Kronecker product of matrices with GSL

Tags: c, algorithm, matrix, product, gsl

The bottleneck of my algorithm is my function Kronecker Product called KPro:

```
gsl_matrix *KPro(gsl_matrix *a, gsl_matrix *b) {
    int i, j, k, l;
    int m, p, n, q;
    m = a->size1;
    p = a->size2;
    n = b->size1;
    q = b->size2;

    gsl_matrix *c = gsl_matrix_alloc(m*n, p*q);
    double da, db;

     for (i = 0; i < m; i++)    {
          for (j = 0; j < p; j++)   {
              da = gsl_matrix_get (a, i, j);
              for (k = 0; k < n; k++)   {
                  for (l = 0; l < q; l++)   {
                      db = gsl_matrix_get (b, k, l);
                      gsl_matrix_set (c, n*i+k, q*j+l, da * db);                
                  }
              }
          }
      }

    return c;
}
```

Do you know an efficient implementation using GSL? I can't find a suitable routine.

Comment: Did you finally work this out? I have the same problem and any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Only looking superficially I can see lot of possible bottlenecks in your routine:

1. Reuse the matrix c rather than re-allocating it each time i.e. promote from function stack variable to class member or static to the file. Allocate it once and to the maximum possible problem size.
2. calling all these gsl_matrix_get and gsl_matrix_set will certainly prevent the compiler from autovectorizing your code, consider instead using a template-based matrix implementation with overloaded or inlined operators and direct memory accesses.
3. Think about the matrix ordering you are using: is it row major? or column major? Cache misses are more expensive than anything else you are doing there. You want to take advantage of spatial locality and reuse, do so by reordering the loop in a way that the innermost loop (where the computation happens) accesses adjacent matrix elements that have been prefetched.
4. Do aligned memory allocation, makes it easier and more efficient to vectorize.
5. Consider using loop unrolling and blocking

Answer (score 0):

You can significantly improve the performance by 'blocking' and utilizing cache memory more effectively.

Take a look at this [paper](http://suif.stanford.edu/papers/lam-asplos91.pdf).  Is has pseudo code that I think you will be able to easily turn into C code.  It also has an algorithm to figure out the optimum block size given cache size and matrix parameters.