# Returning a 2D vector

Tags: c++, function, matrix, vector, return

I am writing a simple C++ program to do a kronecker tensor product of two matrices like the matlab function [kron](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/kron.html)

Here is the program:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>

using namespace std;

vector< vector<double> > kron(vector< vector<double> > &A, vector< vector<double> > &B);

int main()
{


    vector< vector<double> > a = {{1,-2},{-1,0}}; // matrices a and b
    vector< vector<double> > b = {{4,-3},{2,3}};

    int m = a.size()*b.size();
    int n = a[0].size()*b[0].size();

    vector< vector<double> > T(m,vector<double>(n,0.0));

    T = kron(a,b);


    // Display the resulting matrix T
    for(int i  = 0; i < T.size(); i++)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < T[0].size(); j++)
        {
            cout << T[i][j] << ",";
        }

        cout << endl;
    }


    return 0;
}

vector< vector<double> > kron(vector< vector<double> > &A, vector< vector<double> > &B)
{
    int krnProdRow = A.size()*B.size();
    int krnProdCol = A[0].size()*B[0].size();
    int nRowA = A.size();
    int nColA = A[0].size();
    int nRowB = B.size();
    int nColB = B[0].size();

    vector< vector<double> > krnProd(krnProdRow,vector<double>(krnProdCol,0.0));

    int i,j,k,l;

    for(i=0; i<nRowA; i++)
    {
        for(k=0; k<nRowB; k++)
        {
            for(j=0; j<nColA ; j++)
            {
                for(l=0; l<nColB; l++)
                {
                    krnProd[i+l+1][j+k+1] = A[i][j]*B[k][l];
                                //cout << krnProd[i+l+1][j+k+1] << ",";
                }
            }
            //cout << endl;;
        }
    }

    return krnProd;
}
```

When returning the matrix krnProd from the function and assigning it to the T matrix in my main function, I get the following matrix:

```
0, 0, 0, 0
0, 4, 2, -4
0, -4, -2, 0
0, 3, -3, 0
```

which is totally wrong.

However, if i print out the krnProd matrix inside the function itself, I get:

```
4, -3, -8, 6
2, 3, -4, -6
-4, 3, 0, 0
-2, -3, 0, 0
```

which happens to be the true answer. I was wondering, why am I getting a different answer when returning the matrix from the function ? did i overlooked something here ? or the way I am returning the 2D vector is wrong ?

Comment: I can't spot anything is wrong with returning the vector like you did.

Comment: If you display inside function is your commented code, you don't display in same order.

Comment: But you should probably use `for(int j = 0; j < T[i].size(); j++)` when printing the result. Otherwise you refer to the 1st row always.

Comment: And you overwrite your result as `i+l+1` when `i, j` is then `j, i`.

Comment: `n` and `m` are not necessary in `main`. `T` can simply be initialised as `vector< vector<double> > T  = kron(a,b);`. Even better, make it `const`, and in C++11, consider `auto`: `auto const T  = kron(a,b);`

Comment: Thanks, but i have solved the problem. I will post it.

Comment: In `main`, remove `m` and `n` and change to `vector< vector<double> > T;` . Or even better `auto T =  kron(a,b);` to enable copy elision.   The vector assignment also assigns the dimensions (and frees anything previously allocated) so you just waste time allocating and deallocating memory here.

Answer (score 2):

Your matrix is dimensioned with `rowA*rowB` rows and `colA*colB` cols. This is wrong. Given how you are accessing the elements (i.e. using `i+l'` and `j+k`) they should be `rowA+colB` and `colA+rowB`.

Also you're accessing the elements at

```
krnProd[i+l+1][j+k+1]
```

and it's not clear why you're adding 1. I'd make the changes:

```
int krnProdRow = A.size() + B[0].size();
int krnProdCol = A[0].size() + B.size();
```

and

```
krnProd[i+l][j+k] = ...
```

The debug print you're doing is not really about the matrix you're returning, but just all the computed values in the order you're computing them.

Putting the debug print after the computation will show you the same results you're getting in `main`... returning a vector of vectors is perfectly supported by C++.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I understand the mistake now. regarding the SUM, A kronecker tensor product between two matrix say A with size m x n and B with size p x q would return a resulting larger matrix C with size m*p x n*q.

Comment: @tarmizi: Consider the limit case of `m=n=p=q=1`... do you expect the result to be `2×2` or `1×1`? `(mp×nq)` is not the right formula. Note also that you're accessing the result matrix with `i+l` and `j+k` (adding the index or row/column) and this means the matrix number of rows and number of columns should be a sum...

Comment: thanks, that one was a mistake. I believe I have solved the problem. I posted it below. =)

Answer (score 0):

After cracking my head around in finding the index relation of the for loops to do the kronecker tensor product. I finally got the index relation of the for loops to do the calculation from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13722543/efficient-way-to-compute-kronecker-product-of-matrices-with-gsl) question. Thanks to that question, Here is the solution:

```
vector< vector<double> > kron(vector< vector<double> > &A, vector< vector<double> > &B)
{
    size_t krnProdRow = A.size()*B.size();
    size_t krnProdCol = A[0].size()*B[0].size();
    size_t nRowA = A.size();
    size_t nColA = A[0].size();
    size_t nRowB = B.size();
    size_t nColB = B[0].size();

    vector< vector<double> > krnProd(krnProdRow,vector<double>(krnProdCol,0.0));

    size_t i,j,k,l;
    double valA =0.0;
    double valB = 0.0;

    // Looping for kronecker tensor products of A and B
    // Trace the index of the loops to understand the kronecker tensor product
    for(i = 0; i <nRowA ; i++)
    {
        for(j = 0; j < nColA; j++)
        {
            valA = A[i][j];

            for(k = 0; k < nRowB; k++)
            {
                for(l = 0; l < nColB; l++)
                {
                    valB = B[k][l];
                    krnProd[nRowB*i+k][nColB*j+l] = valA * valB;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return krnProd;
}
```

Thanks again everyone for your time.